# Encrypting programs

Tags: encryption

So I’m trying to understand what the process is of encrypting a program I wrote. How does it work. When you encrypt something can that executable be ran without a key? Is there a key that is used? 
If you can explain this or add some links that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different approaches to protecting code. They all fall under the category of DRM (Digital Rights Management).

These are what come to mind for me:

1. Encryption, actually modifying the byte codes in such a way that they can only be executed if a key or password is provided.
2. Obfuscation, rearranging code into a way that is still fully executable as is, but reversing by hand is tedious because the code is purposely arranged into a non-standard/confusing order.
3. Shield, protecting active code that has been loaded into runtime memory. This can be done either with another process that is performing real-time memory checking with checksums. Or it can be done via in memory code encryption with the key stored somewhere in memory that only the application knows where to find it.

There are so many options for DRM, that I'd have trouble picking any implementations that stand out to list here. A simple google search should help point you in the direction of actual implementations.